# How to display days in "rd", "th", "nd", and "st" format in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

guys,

I have to display the day of tomorrow in the format: January 10th of year 2019.
I created this query:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((SYSDATE + 1),'Month DD (ddspth) "of year" YYYY') AS tomorrow FROM DUAL;
```

The output is:

```
May       23 (twenty-third) of year 2023
```

How can I get the output in the desired format?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `sp`ell the word out; and [use `FM`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-7FF68D9E-C7E2-4CA1-9DDB-5CC7169EEEEA) to suppress blank padding:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR((SYSDATE + 1),'FMMonth ddth "of year" YYYY') AS tomorrow FROM DUAL;

May 24th of year 2022
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=b045d9185a44764c2cc7dd319b6d66c3) demo.

Month names are NLS-sensitive, so someone running this in a session with a different date language set will see something else - which you can override. The [`th` will be in English anyway](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-515DFB76-E853-432F-BFEC-F1C62306BEC5), as will your character literal part. You might want to force the month names to English to match. That might be beyond the requirements for this exercise but I've included how to to it in the db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

For a more European style (i.e. day then month, then year): how to amend the above solution wasn't immediately obvious (to me).  But this works well:

SELECT TO_CHAR((SYSDATE + 1),'FMddth Month "of year" YYYY') AS tomorrow FROM DUAL;

24th May of year 2022

-mobailey

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33269236)